# How to fix MySQL 8 replication error 1062 after system reboot?

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

after a system reboot my replication stopped suddenly. So I'm trying to bring the slave back to the most current state.

To do this I create a dump from the master's database and import it on the slave, like

```
mysqldump --host=MASTERADDR --port=MYPORT -u root --password=DBPASS DBNAME > FILE.sql
mysql --host=SLAVEADDR --port=MYPORT -u root --password=DBPASS DBNAME < FILE.sql
```

Then on the slave I "restart" my replication:

```
STOP SLAVE;
RESET SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST = 'MASTERADDR', MASTER_PORT = MYPORT, MASTER_USER = 'REPLUSER', MASTER_PASSWORD = 'REPLPW', MASTER_AUTO_POSITION = 1;
START SLAVE;
SELECT SLEEP(1);
SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
```

This worked pretty well in the past. But now I get the following error code:

```
Last_Errno: 1062
Last_Error: Coordinator stopped because there were error(s) in the worker(s). The most recent failure being: Worker 1 failed executing transaction '691042d7-6ca8-11ed-a122-0242ac120002:4' at master log mysql-bin.000001, end_log_pos 1938. See error log and/or performance_schema.replication_applier_status_by_worker table for more details about this failure or others, if any.
```

I already tried to:

```
SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER=1;
```

But this doesn't work and seems to be ignored.

Please, what can I do to start my replication again?

Answer (score 1):

`MASTER_AUTO_POSITION = 1;` is probably invalid.  0 or 4 is the start of the binlog.  But you have not specified which binlog.

`SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER=1;` says to skip the next command in the replication stream.  *This is destructive, and should not be used without knowing what query is being skipped.*

`RESET SLAVE` is rather drastic, too.

Do you have all the binlogs since the system was set up?  If not do you have a particular point (binlog name + pos)?  (It sounds like you don't.)

Is GTID enabled?

Bottom line, I suspect you need to rebuild the Replica from the Primary.

Homework:  Read a lot more about Replication.